# File and Printer Sharing Port issue in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

On a Windows 7 64 bit box, whenever I try to access a server using file share, it tries to connect to port 80 http on the place of 445. I observed that using WireShark. Telnet to 445 works.

I have scanned the machine using Malware bytes, Symantec and MS Live Essentials. I don't want to recreate the whole machine again.  How can I fix the ports?

Answer (score 0):

Does it do this when you try to access the share using the unc name (eg click on Start and then type either \ServerName or \serverName\shareName)

On my system, when I double click on Computer and then select Network on the left hand panel, I see a list of all my networked devices. For one of these computers it shows up twice. Once under the list of computers and then again under 'Other Devices'. The name on both devices is the same (ie the server name). The first icon will access the file share as normal, whereas the second is some sort of UPNP detection and displays a webpage which tells me a bit about the device and also gives me a link to download some software to backup my machine to the server.

Is it possible you are trying to access the server via some icon like this? If it is, then when you right click on the icon. I think you will get a 'View Device Webpage' option on the menu, rather than the normal 'Open'.

Comment: It does this, when I use windows run prompt . nothing special . no icon

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to connect using WebDav or the WebClient networking provider. Is your WebClient service running on your machine and does it make any difference it is is stopped? Also check that Netbios is not disabled on your Tcp/Ip settings. Finally check your registry value  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\NetworkProvider\Order. On mine it is RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,LMIRfsClientNP, but I think you need to make sure that LanmanWorkstation is before webclient.